# Java: Averaging driving route

Tags: android, java, maps, gps

I have an Android/Java app that continually plots your locations and draws lines connecting sequential points, so I get the route that I have taken on a map. The route will be continuously drawn, as the same path is continually repeated, so that it looks like some type of closed polygon.

Right now it looks like a bunch of "spaghetti" routes and I need to be able to average out the haul route so that if I have 20 cycles, instead of 20 separate haul routes, I want one haul route that is the average of all 20 routes. Mathematically it seems I need some type of library that performs a least squares regression/ polygon fitting model to get what I want. Or I need to way to grid my route and take the best fitting curve in each sub-plot section.

Just wondering if anyone knows of any libraries like this or if Google provides something like this in its API? Hoping maybe there is a simple solution that I'm not aware of that visually picks up on the neighboring points. I could potentially get vector heading if need be.